# Trying to get ordered query of all records added in last 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a chat server using a web server and MySQL. I would like it to show the last chats for within 1 hour time period.
Right now my query is:

```
select * from chats where chat_id = 1 order by time
```

where time is a timestamp.

Comment: Please do not put tags into the title [it is unnecessary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Also, you can mark-up code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button or pressing ctrl+k. It's polite to show some effort yourself and try to make your question readable for others.

Comment: getting the chat of last one hour the query should contains **desc** keyword. i.e. *order by time desc*

Comment: And you should state your question. You only showed us what you did, but not what your problem is. No error message, no description on what you expect to see, no description on what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM `chats` WHERE `chat_id` = 1 
AND `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
ORDER BY `time`
```